# How to close an open Excel file in R

Tags: r, excel

I have an R file that executes some code and then writes the outcomes to an Excel file. I want to create a button in Excel to execute this R file. Creating a button in a separate Excel file works, but if the button is in the file to which R writes, it doesn't work, because R only writes to files that aren't currently used.

Therefore, if I could add a line in R that closes the Excel file, then the writing to the closed Excel file will not be a problem. (I also want to open the file again afterwards)

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2):

You can send system commands using the R command `system()`

I just tested out the following with Excel open on a windows machine, which worked:
`system("taskkill /IM Excel.exe")`

Referenced this answer for how to close programs: https://superuser.com/questions/727724/close-programs-from-the-command-line-windows

Comment: I tried this and it works when I run this command in R. However when I push the button in Excel that executes the code I get an error in Excel. This pops up: "can't close Microsoft Excel". I figure this is because the macro isn't finished yet (it orders to execute the whole R file) when R orders to close Excel.

Comment: Perhaps you can search the referenced superuser answer or elsewhere to find a system command that would override Excel's objection and force it to close, a la Alt+F4. I don't know how that might impact your Excel file or macro. Perhaps you could also program a delay in the R script with `Sys.sleep()` and close Excel yourself  after the macro finishes but before your script gets to the interaction with your file.